# How to apply a function (numpy ufunc) with two array arguments to one pandas Series?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

The second argument should simply be the same scalar for each element of the array.

I simply want to extract the month and day from a numeric code of YYYYMMMDD. I would take `numpy.mod(datenum,10000)` for each value, but the [numpy ufunc mod](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mod.html#numpy.mod) takes two array-like arguments.

Following [instructions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on pandas.apply, I tried and failed with the following test code:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import *

s = Series(np.random.randn(5), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
t = s.apply(np.mod,raw=True,args=(10000,))
print s
print t

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "…", line 7, in <module>
    t = s.apply(np.mod,raw=True,args=(10000,))
  File "…/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2023, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "inference.pyx", line 920, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:44780)
  File "…/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2012, in <lambda>
    f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwds)
TypeError: 'raw' is an invalid keyword to ufunc 'remainder'
```

Without `raw=True`, the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "…", line 7, in <module>
    t = s.apply(np.mod,args=(10000,))
  File "…/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2017, in apply
    return f(self)
ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

How does this work?

Comment: How is `s` supposed to represent dates, anyway? You're drawing floats from a standard normal distribution; the result isn't going to look anything like an 8-digit date.

Comment: This is my test code, I can make it clearer in a quick edit. But how would I specify `10000` for `mod`, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the broadcasting rules, 10000 is arraylike, and you can just pass it to `mod` or `%` as if it were an array:

```
In [13]: s
Out[13]: 
a    85626286                                                                                    
b    66577463                                                                                    
c    75552690                                                                                    
d    36817240                                                                                    
e    75994944                                                                                    
dtype: int64                                                                                     

In [14]: s % 10000
Out[14]: 
a    6286                                                                                        
b    7463                                                                                        
c    2690                                                                                        
d    7240                                                                                        
e    4944                                                                                        
dtype: int64
```

As for `apply`, you're looking at the wrong documentation. You're looking at [`Dataframe.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), but you have a series, so you should be looking at [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html). `Series.apply` doesn't take a `raw` argument.

You might think that removing the `raw` argument would fix your attempt, but `Series.apply` has a peculiar behavior where if `f` is a ufunc and no keyword arguments to `f` are supplied, [it completely ignores `args`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/series.py#L2007). I think this is actually a bug. The workaround is to not use `apply` for this; the broadcasting rules make `apply` redundant for your situation.

Comment: Beautiful. I still don't know how apply should work if I need it again, but this solves the problem at hand. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, note that this is not really an answer for the question as stated. I would give you credit, but this would mislead others finding the question for an answer on `apply.` Sorry…

Comment: @László: Well, this *is* how you apply a NumPy ufunc in the way you want. I've expanded the answer explaining why your attempt failed; does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the answer. Maybe you could be even clearer about no use of apply could broadcast (if that's the right word) the second argument if the ufunc expects an array.

Comment: @László: Well, actually, it could broadcast. I got mixed up a bit about how passing the entire series as an argument would work. The real problem with just removing the `raw` argument seems to be a bug in `Series.apply` that causes it to ignore `args`. I've edited the answer again.